# VirtualBox отклонение usb устроиств

Tags: virtualbox, usb, kernel

Сегодня понадобилось срочно поставить на VM, Windows7 (Максимальная x64), Проблема - все поставилось без проблем, но когда подключаю к виртуалке флешку, Wifi адаптер, любое usb устройство он пишет что не получается установить драйвера, но я лично для адаптера установил драйвера из основы, и там работает без проблем, ощущение что сама система на уровне ядра блокирует usb входы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вроде решил проблему, но ненадолго[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там же видно что сеть легла (внизу справа) но дело может быть еще не в этом,мало скринов, мало инфы (настройки, хост)

Comment: а где версия VirtualBox, версия GuestAdditions, версия VBoxExtentions, какая ОС у хоста?

Comment: Скачивал все с офф. Сайта все одной версии 6.1.16 вроде бы

Comment: Дело не только в адаптере, в любом usb устройстве он не хочет ставить драйвера, 6.1.16 кажется версия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извиняюсь за свою не внимательность, забыл настроить в самом виртуал боксе, кому интересно надо зайти в настройки машины, далее найти usb в списке, и переключить с usb 1.1 на usb 2.0/3.0 (в какой разъем вы ставите флешку)

Comment: Немного дополню: если у вас нет пунктов `USB 2.0/3.0` в списке - нужно установить `VirtualBox Extension Pack` с [с сайта VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)